# R: Error with polr(): initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Tags: r

I'm trying to estimate an ordered probit model using polr:
polr(Rating ~ Currac + Debt + Inflation + GDPpc + GDPgr + Ratio + Levelofdev
+ Eurozone + Default, method ="probit")

where Rating is an ordered discrete dependent variable and the independent
variables are a set of economic determinants (e.g. inflation rate).

However, I keep getting the same error:

*Error in optim(s0, fmin, gmin, method = "BFGS", ...) : 
initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite*

I found it in the C code (src/main/optim.c), at line 523 in the procedure
vmmin. An error is thrown because the result of function fminfn is not
finite. In this function fminfn, at line 82, the result is calculated as
result = REAL(s)[0]/(OS->fnscale). This does not make much sense to me,
however.

I understood it should have something to do with a function evaluating at an
infinite value at the starting values. I was hoping someone could explain
this in more detail, or help me overcome the problem.

Exluding/omitting NA-values from the dataset does not resolve the problem.
However, when I delete **either** Inflation or GDPpc from the set of
regressors, it suddenly works fine. And when I delete everything else but
keep both Inflation and GDPpc, it also still works.

If you have experienced the same problem or might know how to deal with
this, I would be really grateful for your response.

Thanks a lot,

Wouter

Comment: What may be happening here is that the default procedure for generating initial values works poorly for your model and results in a log-likelihood of negative infinity. The optimizer isn't going to be able to handle that case.One approach to this is to manually specify some initial values that work (this may take some guesswork). You can do this via the`start` parameter. Note this will only work if your model is actually possible to estimate and this is purely an initial value problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a very similar issue when using polr() for ordered logistic regression. I was able get the algorithm to converge using the orm function in the rms package https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/6.0-1/topics/orm

Still worth investigating how the distribution of Inflation and GDPpc differs from each of the other independent variables in your model across Rating.

Answer (score 1):

## Change the start parameters

As [jrdnmdhl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4876607/jrdnmdhl) points out in the comments, this could be because of poor initial values. These are the first guess of the coefficients and intercepts. If they're not a good guess it's harder to get accurate answers, hence the error.

You can make your own guess and add them to the `start` argument.

### An example

I had a simple model `m1` which worked and a more complicated model which didn't `m2`. I took the coefficients and intercept estimated successfully in the `m1` and used them for `m2` because these should be close to the "correct" values. For the extra terms of the complex model I used zero as a first guess (but it could have been anything).

```
m1 <- polr(y ~ a, data = example)
```

Get the simple model coefficients (`m1$coefficients`) and intercepts (`m1$zeta`). Put a zero at the end of the coefficients for any new regression parameters in the complex model. In my case there's just one, `b`.

```
myGuess <- c(m1$coefficients, 0, m1$zeta)
```

Use this new vector as a `start` argument.

```
m2 <- polr(y ~ a+b, data = example, start = myGuess)
```

If zero doesn't work try your own best guess for the regression coefficient.